# Different product name for iPhone and iPad

Tags: xcode, ios8

Is it possible to specify a different product name for iPhone and iPad in a universal app?  My app name gets truncated on iPhone but not on iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a different product name by using device specific Keys.

For iPad just add a suffix to **CFBundleDisplayName** like **CFBundleDisplayName~ipad**

for more detail https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html